# Filter_Key by Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, filter

I'm having a terrible time understanding how to get a decent amount of posts/stories when using a filter by application id. I have tried FQL, stream.get, and even using the sk query string in Facebook, and essentially my data is limited to 3 days. What could be causing this. You can get an idea of what's happening by visiting

https://facebook.com/?sk=app_6628568379

This is a filter by the iPhone app. It only goes back 3 days. The application I'm creating relies on getting more than just that back. I would be ok with the standard 50 posts or 30 days, but frankly, 3 days just is unacceptable.

Any thoughts? Has any one else seen this?

EDIT: Here is an FQL query that won't go back very far. This one did go back 9 days, but it's still not 30.

```sql
SELECT app_id, message, created_time, source_id, likes FROM 
stream WHERE filter_key="app_350685531728" LIMIT 1000;
```

Alex

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API: How to filter home & feed by application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910725/facebook-graph-api-how-to-filter-home-feed-by-application)

Answer (score 1):

I just found this answer on another post: [filter by app id via graph call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8874108/830304)

So essentially you can make a graph call, and add me/home?filter=app_[app_id]. Nice.

But to your question, set the "until" to a unix time that is 3 months ago: i.e.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?filter=app_[app_id]&since=[unix time of 3 months ago]

Comment: I hope you also flagged **this** post as a dupe of the one you posted... :)

Comment: You lost me- how do I do that? (sorry new to SO) ah, I see, you added it in comment. Will do so next time, thanks for the tip.

Comment: [Flag the post and mark it as a *duplicate* flag](http://i.imgur.com/CFDuR.png), then choose `"Exact Duplicate"` and paste the link to the duplicate there...

Comment: actually this isn't a duplicate, his question is more "how to expand the timeframe/get more results"

Comment: @AnnaBillstrom - Correct. No matter how long I tell it to go back, it's always only 3 days.

Comment: @AlexBreshears can you post your query