# Facebook Graph API: How to filter home & feed by application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook Graph API lets you grab a JSON representation of home (News Feed) & feed (Wall).

How do I just get the posts made by my Facebook app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now run [Facebook Query Language (FQL)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) queries using the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) (base URL: `https://graph.facebook.com`).

Let's say your application is Twitter. Twitter's Facebook application ID is 2231777543.

I came up with the FQL queries below with the help of [@danontheline's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910725/facebook-graph-api-how-to-filter-home-feed-by-application/7910802#7910802) and by carefully reading Facebook's documentation on [FQL stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) & [FQL stream_filter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter/).

The following excerpt is particularly pertinent:

> If you specify a `filter_key` from the `stream_filter` FQL table or
>   multiple users, results returned will behave like the user's homepage
>   news feed. If only one user is specified as the source_id, you will
>   receive the profile view of the user or page. You can filter these
>   profile view posts by specifying `filter_key` 'others' (return only
>   posts that are by someone other than the specified user) or 'owner'
>   (return only posts made by the specified user). The profile view,
>   unlike the homepage view, returns older data from our databases. In
>   the case of a Page, the profile view also includes posts by fans.

#### Twitter Tweets on Your Facebook News Feed

```
GET /fql?q=SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, app_id, attribution FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'app_2231777543'
```

#### Twitter Tweets on Your Facebook Wall

```
GET /fql?q=SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, app_id, attribution FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND app_id = '2231777543' LIMIT 1000
```

Running these queries with the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) returns [Facebook Graph API post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) objects (The result set will differ depending on `access_token`, privacy, etc.). You can find out more about each post by adding other columns of the stream table to the queries above and/or by simply making another Graph API request to `GET /{post_id}` for eache `post_id` returned by the FQL stream queries above.

Comment: `Version 2.0 of the Facebook Platform API is the last version where FQL will be available. Versions after 2.0 will not support FQL.`

Answer (score 11):

Facebook has added support to filter `me/home` posts without using FQL by passing the `filter` parameter.

For example to get just photos you can do: 
`me/home?filter=app_2305272732`

Full documentation is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home

Comment: This is actually the right answer - doing an FQL stream_filter query is less reliable/less results (for various FB reasons, ha) than the graph pull with filter in the path.

Comment: I see nothing at the link given in this answer to do with a `filter` parameter. Is this the wrong link?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik thats not possible with *just* the Graph API. But you can just use a [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) statement to retrieve the wall/feed, too. With this technique you are able to resrict it to the posts made by one actor_id (which should be your app ID in this case):

```
SELECT post_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0 AND actor_id = 'MattDiPasqualesAppID'
```

Thing here is that it won't return a JSON, but a XML representation of the result. With phps [DOM class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) you are easily able to convert it into a JSON format or any other representation you want to have of the result!

As you might be handling the whole thing with PHP anyway, you also could just take the json array, parse it into an array and filter the array with keys of your appID.

Comment: Nice! Close but not quite. Thanks to your answer, however, I was able to figure out [how to filter Facebook Graph home & feed by application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910725/facebook-graph-api-how-to-filter-home-feed-by-application/7912712#7912712). Plus, the new Facebook Graph API returns JSON, not XML. PHP is awesome, but I prefer Ruby.