# Is there any way to find app activity on users wall?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am just wondering if there is a way to find for example all post_id's that has been posted on users wall by app?
Or something similar to get these posts that has been posted by app - preferably their ids?

I'm not sure this require `read_stream` permission.

Comment: How about counsulting the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0

Comment: @Tobi I didn't find anything that would let me do it in 2 hours of searching web, developer docs for both fql and graph-api. I'm asking bcuz I did not found anything that would let me do it.

Comment: I can't really believe that, because looking at the FQL `stream` table would have clearly given you an idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FQL `stream` table can be used to query for posts created by a certain app (if you know the app's id):

```
select post_id, app_id, message, created_time from stream where source_id=me() and app_id={app_id} limit 100
```

where `{app_id}` is the numeric id of the app. You'll need `read_stream` permission to run the query for specific users.

As the `read_stream` permission *is reserved for apps that replicate the Facebook client on platforms that don’t have a native client* (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended-read), it's unlikely that this can be used in an v2.0 app. If the app is v1.0, it should work until April 30th 2015.

Alternatively, you could use the

```
/me/home?filter=app_{app_id}
```

as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8874108/1603357 Instagram would be `app_124024574287414` for example. Unfortunately, this also requires `read_stream`.

Comment: since `read_stream` is reserved for platforms that has not their native apps, that won't work if I understand `read_stream` correctly. Edit: I mean it won't work for android app since `read_stream` is not availble there. At least it is what I think, from what I read.

Comment: That would be new to me, which doesn't mean it's impossible :-) Where's the source? And, if that would be true, there would be no chance for you to get the data, because Facebook is using OAuth, so everything is permission-based.

Comment: [Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended-read) Seems like its for TVs etc. apps developers. That is why I was asking, if there is other way to get this data. Anyway thanks for info and fqlquery dunno if I should mark this as answered?

Comment: Ok, I learned something here... I'd say bad luck for you if you need to use v2.0. With v1.0 this should be possible, but it will vanish on April 30th 2015

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Added some info regarding a non-FQl solution.